# Why is my GLFW window so slow?

Tags: performance, opengl

For some reason the following code produces a result such as this: [image]

I have no idea why it takes a second or two to render each frame. The code seems to be normal to me, but I have no idea why it renders it so slowly.

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include"GL/glew.c"
#include"GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include<cmath>
#include<ctime>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main( ) {
    // init glfw
    if ( !glfwInit( ) ) return 0;

    // create window and set active context
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow( 640, 480, "Test", NULL, NULL );
    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );

    // init glew
    if ( glewInit( ) != GLEW_OK ) return 0;

    // set swap interval
    glfwSwapInterval( 1 );

    // render loop
    while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) ) {
        srand( time( NULL ) );
        float r = ( rand( ) % 100 ) / 100.0;

        float ratio;
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize( window, &width, &height );
        ratio = width / ( float ) height;
        glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );

        // render
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
        glClearColor( r, 0, 0, 1 );

        // swap
        glfwSwapBuffers( window );

        // events
        glfwPollEvents( );
    }

    // terminate glfw
    glfwTerminate( );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your GLFW code is correct, and it is performing much faster than you think.

This is incorrect usage of `rand` and `srand`. More concretely, you `srand` with the current time (measured in seconds) every time you render, which will, within the same second, produce exactly the same value for `r` every time.

You therefore clear the screen to the same color several hundred times per second. This *looks like* it only renders at one frame per second, but it really isn't.

There are a few other problems with your code (such as using `rand()%100` which gives a biased distribution. and using some OpenGL commands redundantly), but the one thing you need to fix for your immediate problem is:  `srand` only once, not every time you render.

Comment: About using modulo with `rand`, consider the difference between `r = (rand()%100)/100.0;` and `r = (rand()%256)/255.0;`. What happens to `r` if `rand()` returns the values 1, 101, and 201? Compare the two cases. You will find that modulo any non-power-of-two number will cause some outputs to appear 2-3 times as often than others. That can be very disturbing if you assume that numbers are equidistributed.